# What is 'Forget it Tracy. It's Midtown' a reference to in 30 Rock

Tags: plot-explanation, 30-rock

In season 6, episode 10 [Alexis Goodlooking and the Case of the Missing Whisky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2239015/?ref_=ttep_ep10) Jenna and Tracy are trying to solve who drank Pete's Whisky.

Midway through the episode Jenna turns to Tracy and says

[Forget it Tracy.
It's Midtown](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=30-rock&episode=s06e10)

This is clearly a nod to the ending of Chinatown but what is Midtown in this context? Is there something specific about Midtown New York? I'm not a US resident so the reference is lost to me.

I'm asking if there is something notorious about midtown Manhattan, whether it's somehow different, off-limits, dangerous, not to be trusted etc.. Rather than the fact it's the geographical location of the studio.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming she's talking about [Midtown Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midtown_Manhattan), where the show takes place. I'm not sure what you're asking, actually...

Comment: I'm wondering if there is another reason rather than just geographical, i.e. is midtown dangerous, crooked, not to be trusted, somehow alien is what I'm asking, will edit into the question

Comment: I don't think so. I think she's just paraphrasing the Chinatown quote to fit where they are, like you said.

Comment: @Walt was hoping there was something more to it than just paraphrasing the quote

Comment: Well, maybe something will pop up. I'm often wrong. ;)

Comment: It's a reference to the last line of Chinatown.

Comment: @BenPlont that's already stated in my question, I'm wondering if there is some other significance about midtown manhattan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an American who has lived in Manhattan, and I don't know of anything unique about Midtown Manhattan that would make sense in this joke. Therefore, I think it's safe to conclude **the line has no significance beyond the reference to *Chinatown***.

Comment: That's a shame I was hoping for some *in-joke*, thanks for the answer I'll see if anyone else has any further insights